# exclude subdirectories in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

I have installed TypeScript 1.8.2, and using Visual Studio 2015. I have a simple project where I have problems excluding folders from the tsconfig.json file. The problem is I would like to exclude the file typings/browser.d.ts and the folder typings/browser. But this is not the case?

I have no problems excluding a subfolder, but not a sub-subfolder?

[NOTE]
I just realized the problem is only when I build from Visual Studio! If i build with tsc from the command line, there's no problem. Could I have another version of TypeScript in Visual Studio? How can I check this?

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "public",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have a bigger project, where I use jspm and need to exclude the jspm package folder, which is located as a subfolder to public.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, with a project that was working flawlessly in visual studio 2015 before I installed the typescript 1.8.2 toolchain for visual studio.  I suspect this is a visual studio tooling bug rather than a setup issue.

Comment: I actually moved from VS 2015 to atom, because of this. And because VS 2015 crashed a bit to too often. Which is sad I like to work in VS..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed and tested the latest version of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 (1.8.6 at the moment), and I can confirm that this problem has been fixed in the latest release.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

[Edit]
Be sure to also do an npm update -g typescript

Comment: this doesn't seem to take effect in `VS 2015 Update 2 RC`. Even though it has installed it keeps showing 1.8.2 from within Extensions manager. I'm hoping Update 2 RTM (which is now available) will fix this

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Did you try installing from the link above after you insatlled Update 2?

Comment: No because it appeared to have a lower version number.

Answer (score 47):

Try with:

```
 "exclude": [
     "node_modules",
     "public",
     "typings/browser.d.ts",
     "typings/browser/**"
 ]
```

Comment: OH! I just realised I could build from command line! And not from VS, so this i probaly a problem with my VS TypeScript setup

Comment: Note that this goes into root config, *not* into "compilerOptions"

Comment: Why is this needed? Node Modules folder doesn't require ** but the browser folder needs it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a problem with typescript being unable to exclude paths/patterns that belong to deeper dir structure. Its still a problem with "typescript@^3.4.5".

To fix this I started cleaning my Dist dir with "rimraf dist" before every test run.

```
"test:unit": "npm run clean && stencil test --spec --snapshot",
```

I know its a hack, but works.

Comment: Where is a reference to this being an issue with typescript, so that we can follow along?

Comment: I can confirm that this bug still exists in VSCode Version: 1.55.2, circa Apr 2021

Answer (score 0):

I am using ts V4.1.3 with webStorm 2021 and an exclude like
exclude:[server/**] in tsconfig.json appeared to not be excluding, however I found it was only compiling if I opened one of the ts files in the editor.

I turned off WebStorm/File/Settings/Languages../TypeScript/Recompile On Changes
and all is ok, ie it does not compile any ts files at any level in the server directory.