# How to exclude folder from typescript check, but still compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I want to build `libs/libb` with `libs/libb/tsconfig.json`. In this tsconfig I have an option `"noImplicitAny": true`. But file in `libb` imports file from `liba`. This file contains a function with arguments with `any` type. So I can't build `libb`. How to exclude `liba` folder from check, but still compile it if `liba` imports it? Here is a minimal reproducible example https://github.com/NazarKalytiuk/typescript-kcf5m9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647862/exclude-subdirectories-in-tsconfig-json

Answer (score 0):

You can *explicitly* annotate the parameters as `any`:

`a.ts`:

```ts
// before
export function testA(a, b) {
    console.log('Hello')
}

// after
export function testA(a: any, b: any) {
    console.log('Hello')
}
```

And if you can't modify the source TypeScript file that you're importing, you can use a [`// @ts-ignore` comment directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) before the line that's causing the problem:

`b.ts`:

```ts
// @ts-ignore
import {testA} from "../liba/a"

function testB(a: number, b: number) {
    console.log('Hello')
    testA(1,2);
}
```

Comment: @ts-ignore in b.ts looks like a good idea, but it didn't help. It works only in a.ts. But I can't change a.ts.